# Angular Project with Bazel needs sudo to start

Tags: angular, macos, permissions, bazel, sudo

I use Bazel to run and build my Angular-project. Since I re-cloned the project (due to some npm/yarn issues), I can't start the project anymore without using sudo:

It worked like this earlier and I want it to work like so:

```
yarn start
```

But now I have to start it like this:

```
sudo yarn start
```

The *yarn start* executes the following command:

```
ibazel run //src/folder:devserver
```

Does anybody know where i have to set the permissions?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting when you try to start it without sudo? It might help us debug your problem.

Comment: I get following error:
iBazel [9:14AM]: Error starting process: fork/exec /var/folders/my/6_j0rh0j5s38rps25q9l9z640000gn/T/bazel_script_path1313556513: permission denied
iBazel [9:14AM]: Run start failed fork/exec /var/folders/my/6_j0rh0j5s38rps25q9l9z640000gn/T/bazel_script_path1313556513: permission denied

Comment: Can you check if there are any flags set in your .bazelrc file, then  remove them.  If you are still seeing this can you share the minimal code to reproduce it.

Comment: Having re-cloned the project worked for me. Thanks for reaching out anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-cloned the repository.